# asynchronus javascript behaviour with sleep/setTimeout function (THREEJS and Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, three.js

I am new to Javascript and asynchronous programming, so I am sure that this is a beginners problem.

I am using ThreeJS to build up a Scene with multiple objects (around 100) and so far everything was working fine.

Now I am trying to render the whole scene in a specific time (after initializing). So with a button click I want the scene to be build up piece by piece. For that I am trying to use a sleep or the setTimeout function. Both don't work for me unfortunately.

```
public buildPalette() {
    if (!this.initial) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numOfItems; i++) {
        this.scene.remove(this.mesh[i + 1]);
      }
      this.initial = true;
    }
    if (this.initial) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numOfItems; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.sleep(100);
        this.scene.add(this.mesh[i + 1]);

    }
  }
```

So here I am first removing all objects from my scene and later I want to build up the scene again object by object every 100ms.

I used the following Sleep function:

```
public sleep(milliseconds) {
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

When executing the code (Angular with Chrome), the first thing that happens is that the sleep function will be executed 100 times and then the scene will be cleared and then build up again initially. I want it to be cleared first and then be build up step by step.

I also tried to use the setTimeout() function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
          this.scene.add(this.mesh[i + 1]);
        }, 100);
```

I just replaced `this.sleep(100);` with the above timeout code in the buildPalette() function.

However, that is not working as well. Here am I getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

So it seems to me that here the scene object is not defined anymore.

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Are there specific conditions that you have to add/remove objects to/from your scene instead of set their `.visible` property to `true`/`false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call setTimeout like , use `()=>{}` instead of `function(){}`

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.scene.add(this.mesh[i + 1]);
}, 100);
```

You can read about that **[HERE](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/)**

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with scopes. When you use the setTimeout, it needs a function as parameter. This function has a separated scope and the "this" would be inside the function. You have to set this to another variable to have access to the real "this":

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
   _this.scene.add(_this.mesh[i + 1]);
}, 100);
```